# Посоветуйте книги по CS для начинающего!

Tags: c++, информатика

Посоветуйте книги(желательно с переводом) по Computer Science для начинающего. В данный момент учу плюсы, уже прочел книгу "Код" Чарльза Петцольда, не знаю, что следующим прочитать. В основном всё годное на английском, а с этим плохо, либо с гугловским переводом, а это не в кайф.

Comment: В свое время мне очень понравилась [Пратт Т., Зелковиц М. Языки программирования. Разработка и реализация](https://www.studmed.ru/pratt-t-zelkovic-m-yazyki-programmirovaniya-razrabotka-i-realizaciya_3a8c7790285.html) / Правда, я читал еще первое издание, но надеюсь, хуже она не стала

Comment: (а [тут](http://e-maxx.ru/bookz/) предлагают и ее и много всего другого сразу в электронном виде...)